# How to change course owner using Classroom.Courses.patch()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to use Apps Script to change the owner of a Google Classroom course.

According to the documentation I can do it using `.patch()`. This is the relevant script:

```
   var body = {            
     ownerId: owner
   }
   var mask={
     mask:'ownerId'
   }
       var optArgs = (mask, body); 

    var course = {
      name: classname,
      courseState: state,
      description: desc,
      descriptionHeading: descHead,
      room: room,
      section: section
    };
       Classroom.Courses.patch(course, courseId,  optArgs )
```

When I run it to update the owner I get the following error message

> Could not be updated Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "ownerId": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'ownerId' could not be found in request message.

Just to demonstrate a contrast, when I run `.update()` instead:

```
Classroom.Courses.update(course, courseId)
```

...the rest of the course details are updated perfectly, however `.update()` doesn't allow you to change the owner; it has to be a `.patch()` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem, the issue is the optArgs - you just want the mask in there, not your changed data.

```
var optArgs = { mask: 'ownerId' }; 

var course = {
  name: classname,
  courseState: state,
  description: desc,
  descriptionHeading: descHead,
  room: room,
  section: section,
  ownerId: owner 
};

Classroom.Courses.patch(course, courseId,  optArgs );
```

Comment: From my experiments (and the badly written docs), `mask` should be `updateMask`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this a few moments ago and it worked. Take into account that, for this to work, the user must already be a teacher in the specific class, and then this will make that teacher the owner.

```
function changeTeacherOwner() { 
var course = { 'ownerId': "EMAIL OF TEACHER" };
Classroom.Courses.patch(course, "COURSE ID",  {'updateMask':'ownerId'}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation, this is working as intended.

[courses.update](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/update) has no `ownerId` parameters, only `id`.

But if you check [courses.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch) it has the `updateMask` parameter which accepts `ownerId` as a valid field.

For detailed information on this service, see the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/) for the Classroom API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if I've not been very clear. My problem is with the courses.patch. I only mentioned courses.update to show that, as far as I can tell, the data I am using are correct. My problem is that I don't understand the documentation on courses.patch well enough to be able to work out what I am doing wrong.